# Keep FFmpeg running

Tags: video, ffmpeg, slideshow

Good morning, I have a script that generates 2 images every second in a folder and I want ffmpeg to convert them into a series of mpeg-4 videos of 5 secs duration and that shows 2 images per second (10 frames total). Problem is that after I start the script and after I run ffmpeg, it processes the videos with the images it catches right after I run the command only and then it closes. I tried with the -re command also and nothing happens. How do I keep ffmpeg running and live converting the images while they're being generated? Here's the code I'm using :

```
ffmpeg -re -framerate 2 -s 1920x1200 -i C:\Desktop\input\%05d.bmp -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0 -segment_time 5 -g 5 -sc_threshold 0 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*5)" -f segment C:\Desktop\output\%05d.mp4
```

All I want is to execute ffmpeg one time and let it work and close only when they're finished generating.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the images. When reading images from files, ffmpeg will identify the last image in the sequence during initialisation and will read till that image.

```
cat images | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -re -framerate 2 -i - -vcodec libx264 ...
```

**Edit**: Not surprisingly cat also sets the input roster at initialisation. However, the method below works for me.

Have the script append the new images to a blob file

i.e.  `cat new-image >> all-images`

while ffmpeg call is

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -re -framerate 2 -i all-images -vcodec libx264 ...
```

It is very important that your new image generation and appendation speed is equal to or faster than ffmpeg's read speed.

Comment: I have Windows, cat won't work. I tried with type but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Get [gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) and you'll have cat.

Comment: got gow, it gives me this error : C:\Desktop\input\%05d.bmp: No such file or directory

Comment: `cat *.bmp` works here.

Comment: it gives me the same error. Maybe I modified my command in a wrong way? Basically now it goes like : cat *.bmp | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -re -framerate 2 -s 1920x1200 -i C:\Desktop\input\%05d.bmp...

Comment: The ffmpeg command should be as shown in my answer.

Comment: This is what it happens when I run it `C:\WINDOWS\system32>cat *bmp | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -re -framerate 2 -i - -vcodec libx264 -vf fps=2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0 -segment_time 5 -g 5 -sc_threshold 0 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*5)" -f segment C:\Desktop\output\%05d.mp4
cat: *bmp: Invalid argument` and `pipe:: End of file` at the end of it.

Comment: It's `cat *.bmp` Mind the dot.

Comment: same error message, cat: *.bmp: Invalid argument. DO I have to setup any new folder? How could FFmpeg know the source path without me specifying it?

Comment: Wait a minute. Why are you running cat from C:\Windows\system32?

Comment: Cause a guide on gow told me to normally run command prompt and commands should've been added in it...

Comment: cd to C:\Desktop\input\ and run it there.

Comment: I tried it there, it gives me no error but it behave like without pipe. FFmpeg stops running while scripts keeps generating images. Plus now, generated videos won't have my images in them but only wrong generated grey images with some random black frames in them.

Answer (score 0):

To keep ffmpeg getting added new images, it will need to get them from stdin.
You will need to write a program or script that will keep feeding it new images
as they arrive.

For examples see:

- [Create video from a growing image sequence using FFMPEG](https://superuser.com/questions/1257122/create-video-from-a-growing-image-sequence-using-ffmpeg)
  for a C# script
- [Use Named Pipe (C++) to send images to FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666661/use-named-pipe-c-to-send-images-to-ffmpeg)
  for a C++ program.

These programs will need some changes to fit them to your needs,
but they are a good starting point.

Comment: I will try them but I would've liked a built-in ffmpeg solution for it cause adding files to the stdin would slow down the process. I thought the -re command should've worked like that?